# How do I run a *.py that's located in ...\Python27\Lib\site-packages\SubFolder?

Tags: python

From the Python interpreter, in DOS, I can import openpyxl stuff and openpyxl is installed in ...Python27/Lib/site-packages.  But, my PATH statement in Windows only includes up to ...Python27, so I just assumed that all subfolders were also accessible since the above worked.  However, when I create a new folder inside of site-packages to keep things more organized, I cannot run any *.py files from there.  Do I need to add a *.pth file in the new folder or modify my PATH any?

Comment: Is there a particular reason *why* you want to run a script you normally just import?

Comment: Not really.  I was just messing around, trying out stuff to see if I could better my understanding of the PATH variable, and get more acquainted with Python.  I have since moved all of those small programs that demonstrate basic OOP concepts away from the Python27 directory tree, because I didn't want to tinker with the Python installation too much and mess it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You will have to modify your PATH variable.

Long answer: If you take a look [how PATH works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) you'll see that Windows and most OS just CD/CHDIR to each of these folders until they find the executable. So it is not expected that it should find executables in the subfolders.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me, gkbonetti.  I had thought that it would be just a modification to the PATH variable.  Then while tracking down answers online, I read something about including *.pth files and I didn't know if that was maybe an exclusive Python thing or not.  I'm glad to see that it's not needed and that just a PATH modification is all that's required.  I would've tested for the answer myself, but I didn't want to mess too much with my Python installation after I had just installed it.  I was going to vote up your answer, but I don't have enough reputation points yet.